# Running a cron in Yii2

Tags: php, cron, yii2

I'm using the advanced template application of yii2 and i want to create a cron.
I could find only little information while googling the subject and so far found that cron jobs should go in the console folder.

my structure:

```
backend/
. 
.
.
console/
    models/
        Subscriptions.php   // my custom table model
    .
    .
    .       
    controllers/
        TimelineController.php
    .
    .
    .
```

I don't know where to go from now or how to proceed? How can I run the cron?

LAMP environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok i had to navigate to the root of the project in the terminal, there exists a script named yii, i used the following command to run the cron:

php yii cronName.

for example a cron controller named FirstController should be run like this:

rootFolderName/ php yii first

Comment: my root folder is `E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web` but when I try to hit on `CMD` it says `... it is not recognized as internal or external command...`

Answer (score 11):

In your app\console\controllers\SampleController

```
class SampleController extends Controller {
        public function actionIndex() {
            echo "cron service runnning";
        }
```

In your terminal,from your application root folder,run..

```
   `php yii sample/index`
```

You should get like `cron service runnning`

Comment: I have got until this. I am inserting a row in a table with this action. When I executed the command a row is inserting in the table. Now how to do on daily basis using windows scheduler. I have configured Program/Script and argument, the task is triggered and completed successfully but the rows are not inserted in the table. Kindly guide me to configure it on windows task scheduler

Comment: How can I run this service after every 1 minute or so using windows ?

Comment: Is it `running` or is it actually spelt `runnning`?

Comment: Mine worked after moving my controller file to commands folder and changing namespace to app\commands

Answer (score 1):

In yii2, command which worked for me is:

- - - - - path/to/php path/to/project/yii command-name